# How can I see in Microsoft OneDrive web interface whether a file is still being uploaded by the Microsoft OneDrive desktop client?

Tags: onedrive

How can I see in Microsoft OneDrive web interface whether a file is still being uploaded by the Microsoft OneDrive desktop client?

Comment: Downvoter: please comment on how I could improve the question

Answer (score 1):

I'll try and answer both sides:

- Onedrive web only shows documents that have been uploaded completely. This is because most sync clients use MD5/SHA (hashes) based synchronisation which means that the file integrity is ensured. It uses an algorithm ([example](http://practicalcryptography.com/hashes/md5-hash/)) to create a value that is is checked with the local client to ensure consistency.
  You can read more about how you can check your file hashes yourself with onedrive in the [onedrive API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/hashes).

I'm unsure which OS you are using, but both Mac and Windows have:

- Activity logs  (when you click on the OneDrive icon (clouds) in Menubar/Taskbar
- Finder/Explorer integration to show status of uploaded file. All files will have [these](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-do-the-onedrive-icons-mean-11143026-8000-44f8-aaa9-67c985aa49b3) icons.

Also it is good to clarify which OneDrive you are using, as there is OneDrive Personal and OneDrive business which works off sharepoint.

If you want to see a list of recently modified files in both you can click on the `Recent` tab on the left hand side in the web interface to see current items you have uploaded.

If you have OneDrive business, you can go to: `Site settings > Storage Metrics` under `Site Collection Administration > Documents` and click `Last Modified` column to get the Modified status about your sync library.

Hope that explains everything a bit!